# How to specify the start of the x-axis at 1 instead of 0

Tags: gnuplot

I use gnuplot to plot execution times measured on the CPU and GPU depending on the data size. So I have two files with the execution times in it. Plotting them is straight forward.

```
set title "CPU vs GPU"

set xlabel "Number of Particles (* 10'000)"
set ylabel "Time in Microseconds"

plot "cpuTimes.txt" title "CPU" with linespoints, \
     "gpuTimes.txt" title "GPU" wit
```

The resulting plot can be found here: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niAd0.png)

I tried to use `xtics` however it doesn't shift the x-axis to start at 1 but just starts the ticks at 1. How can I shift the x-axis so it starts at 1 and ends at 50?

**Update**

Datafile cpuTimes.txt below

```
64780
129664
195490
266697
327871
391777
459150
517999
582959
647984
717377
790415
830869
900475
959599
1026041
1092899
1156022
1297471
1286325
1349227
1415936
1482857
1539580
1607389
1673436
1737098
1801568
1874431
1935975
2006892
2053077
2129867
2195117
2254467
2314478
2373546
2435416
2506850
2587302
2625556
2674799
2758387
2820720
2896794
2953550
3053817
3089501
3170513
3271537
```

Comment: Some would say choosing your axes to hide data is misleading...

Comment: @Tom I think Nils has just a single column of data. Then gnuplot stars plotting at 0 by default. This is however arbitrary. On the other hand I might just not understand the question correctly^^.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xtics` are only to "label" the x-axis. What you are looking for is some sort of "data manipulation". I'd suggest making use of `using` like so:

```
plot "cpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 t "CPU" w lp, \
     "gpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 t "GPU" w lp
```

To make the plot end at 50 there are two ways:

1. You could specify the x-range with `set xrange [1:50]` or with

   ```
   plot [1:50] "cpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 t "CPU" w lp, \
               "gpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 t "GPU" w lp
   ```
2. You need to include `every` like so:

   ```
   plot "cpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 every 1::::50 t "CPU" w lp, \
        "gpuTimes.txt" u ($0+1):1 every 1::::50 t "GPU" w lp
   ```

   See [every](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-12200034.1.3) for documentation for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used gnuplot in awhile, but I believe you can use `set xrange` to adjust what is plotted.

In your case the command is:

```
set xrange [ 1 : 50 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an axis range in your plot command:

```
plot [1:50] "cpuTimes.txt"
```

Comment: Tried plot [1:50] "cpuTimes.txt" title "CPU" with linespoints doesn't work.

Comment: ah it seems to affect the y-axis, but not the x-axis, it should affect the x-axis

Comment: @Nils It would be easier to see what's going on if you provided a fragment of your data file.